# Checking a variable on null value styles

Tags: java

I have 2 java statements:

```
if(myvar!=null)

if(null!=myvar)
```

Some people says that second form is better because it helps to avoid NPEs, is it true? What is generally beter to use in java?

Comment: How does the second format avoid NPEs? Any example?

Comment: What should cause an NPE?? Both are used to avoid them, they will not throw anything.

Comment: The second one is called [Yoda Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) and it looks really bad (in my opinion).

Comment: The second one prevents typos like "myvar=null" because "null=myvar" won't compile. Might save you some trouble.

Comment: @janos yes, it only compiles in rare cases, but especially if you are also developing in other languages it might come handy to get used to this notation (e.g. if you do Javascript)

Comment: This question is tagged Java, specifically. But I see your point, I added that to my answer. (I hate to admit you seem to be right.)

Comment: @janos *"in Java, `null = myvar` will compile only if the type of `myvar` is `Boolean`"* Not really, but I guess you meant `myvar = null`.

Comment: crap, thanks @Tom, yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> if(myvar!=null)
>
> if(null!=myvar)
> ```
>
> Some people says that second form is better because it helps to avoid
>   NPEs, is it true?

No. These are exactly the same, and there is no risk of NPE here to avoid.

Maybe you confused the example with this situation:

> ```
> if (myvar.equals("something"))
>
> if ("something".equals(myvar))
> ```

Here, if `myvar` is `null`, the first form would throw an NPE, since `.equals` would be dereferencing a `null` value, but the second one works just fine, as the `.equals` implementation of `String` handles a `null` parameter gracefully, returning `false` in this example. For this reason, in this example, the 2nd form is generally recommended.

---

A related argument, which one of these is preferred?

> ```
> if (myvar == null)
>
> if (null == myvar)
> ```

Consider the possibility of a typo, writing a single `=` instead of `==`:

> ```
> if (myvar = null)
>
> if (null = myvar)
> ```

If `myvar` is a `Boolean`, then the first form will compile, the second form will not. So it may seem that the second form is safer. However, for any other variable type, neither form will compile. And even in the case of a `Boolean`, the damage is very limited, because regardless of the value of `myvar`, the program will *always crash* with an NPE when the `if` statement is reached, due to unboxing a `null` value.

Since no test will ever get past this statement, and since you should not release untested code, making such mistake is unrealistic.

<strike>In short, the safety benefit is so marginally small that it's practically non-existent, so I don't see a reason to prefer this unusual writing style.</strike>

**Update**

As [@Nitek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155154/nitek) pointed out in a comment, an advantage of adopting the second form could be if you make it a habit, so that when you program in other languages where `myvar = null` might compile, you'd be slightly safer, out of your "good habits".

I'd still point out that in many languages comparisons with `null` are special, with no possibility of such typo errors. For example in Python, `myvar == None` is incorrect, and should be written as `myvar is None`, so there's no more `==` to mistype.

Strictly speaking, although the `null = myvar` writing style will not protect you in all languages, it might protect you in some, so I'd have to admit it seems to be a good habit.

Comment: *"in this example, the 2nd form is preferred"* Luckily not by everyone :D.

Comment: @Tom:  if `myvar` is `null` you really will get an NPE.  It makes far more sense to perform `.equals` on a known non-null reference, since the contract for `equals` generally covers `null`.

Comment: @Makoto And I want to get the NPE there, since `null` is rarely a valid value for variables in my applications. Therefore I did something wrong somewhere and I like to know that, instead of letting `equals` "silently" fail.

Comment: @Tom:  **No.** You want to get `false` on the boolean comparison, lest `boolean` be defined as `true`, `false`, or `null` - the latter inevitably being compared to `null` to get yet another boolean.

Comment: @Makoto To be honest, I currently don't get what you mean with that, can you explain it, please? (

Comment: @Tom:  My comments have been on the `.equals` form, not the `==` form.  That is what it seemed like your comment referred to originally.

Comment: @Makoto My first comment is about my dislike of `"something".equals(myvar)` (well other don't like it, too), because I want to let `myvar.equals("something")` fail with an NPE if `myvar` is `null`. And in the context of `.equals` I don't know what you mean with your last comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true, they are the same.

I prefer the first one because i think it reads better.

```
if(myvar!=null)
```

if myvar is not equal to null

and

```
if(null!=myvar)
```

if null is not equal to myvar

Answer (score 3):

This is primary opinion based, but I always go with

```
if (variable == null)
if (variable != null)
```

because imo it´s a better programming style.

And a short answer to your post, **no difference between them**.

Answer (score 3):

There is no practical difference in your case.

> 15.21. Equality Operators
>
> > The equality operators are commutative if the operand expressions have no side effects.

That is, you *can* have a situation where the LHS and RHS matter because evaluating them can cause a change in the other, but not if one of them is the keyword `null`.

Consider the following example:

```
public class Example {

    static int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(doit() == x); // false
        System.out.println(x == doit()); // true
    }

    static int doit() {

        x++;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Furthermore,

> 15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators == and !=
>
> > The result of != is false if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is true.

shows that there is no difference in the evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no certain difference in both of them both refer to the same check

```
if(myvar!=null)
if(null!=myvar)
```

both are the exact same things.
But in depper context it is the [Yoda Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

It is generally criticized because of its readability issues, so try to make every thing simple for yourself and for other people who might read your code as this is not a standard notation.

Answer (score 0):

As Nitek wrote in the comment to my initial question:

```
The second one prevents typos like "myvar=null" because "null=myvar" won't compile. Might save you some trouble.
```

So, we have a BIG advantage of the second form - it helps to prevent serious logic error. Example:

```
Boolean i=false;
....
if(null=i){

}
```

won't compile
but

```
Boolean i=false;
....
if(i=null){

}
```

will

But the second form has a big disadvantage - it's reading difficulties. 
So I would say that in 99% cases the first form is ok, but I prefer to use the second form. If you are sure you won't mix == and = up, use the first form. If not, use the second. I'm sure there are a couple of other cases when the second form is preferred, but can't remind it at the moment.

Comment: I added an explanation for this case too, see my updated answer.